# Formatting bigdecimals sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

To have a readable big numbers under oracle and to facilatet the reading, I'm looking for a way to add blank space to obtain something like that:

213537592384.236 ===> 213 537 592 384.236

The problem that I have big numbers like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are a curious separator, and not directly supported by `to_char()`.  However, you can format with commas and then replace the commas with spaces:

```
select replace(to_char(12345678.123, '999,999,999,999,999,999.999'), ',', ' ')
from dual
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a space as a group separator with [`to_char()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm#i79330) by specifying it as one of the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` in the third argument.  For example:

```
SQL> select
  2      to_char(213537592384.236,'999G999G999G990D000','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''. ''')
  3  from
  4      dual;

TO_CHAR(213537592384
--------------------
 213 537 592 384.236
```

Comment: there is any difference between your solution and @Gordon Linoff solution ?

Comment: The end result is the same, but the path taken is slightly different.  @GordonLinoff's solution uses `to_char()` to format the number using a period as a decimal separator and a comma as a group (thousands) separator, and then replaces each comma with a space.  My solution does it in one step using to `to_char()` to format the number using a period as a decimal separator (denoted by D in the format and specified as the first of the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`) and a space as the group separator (denoted by G in the format and specified as the second of the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`).